# Getting hold of the error I've just inserted in Spring MVC Form Validator

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

I have the requirement to store the Error object in a custom ArrayList.

When I do this, for example, I lose my Error object and don't see it:

```
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, 
                                                  "addressLine1", 
                                                  "error.field.required", 
                                                  new Object[] { "Street 1" });

// Now need to add the just-specified error to a custom ArrayList...
// myErrorList.add(..) ?
```

The reason I need this is we have to examine our errors in a customized way once we submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

`errors.getFieldError("addressLine1")` will give you the first error associated with the field if any...

Comment: But I don't want the first error. There could multiple errors per field. I need the specific error as defined by field, type, code, etc. That's why I asked for a specific Error object I've just inserted. It's hidden from me behind the scenes.

Comment: Have you tried `errors.getAllErrors` and get the last error from the list? You can also use `errors.getFieldErrors` to get all errors associated with a field